# How to play MP4 video on window webserver in quick time and flash player(flv player)

Tags: asp.net, flash, flvplayer

I have two mp4 video files on webserver, i wanted to play them in flash player(flv player) on my asp.net page, but i couldn't be able to play them, i also tried to play them in quick time player the same prob occured. but i waz giving the accurate path, there were no spaces in mp4 file names etc.

Does it need to have mp4 player(or codec etc) installed on webserver?

I have also some wmv files on that server , and i am playing perfectly using silver light player, and media player object on my website.

So please share your knowledge... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them to FLV first. I use a program called [AVS Video Convertor](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Video-Converter.aspx), its not free but is a great tool.

Comment: Thank you Rippo, whaht is the solution to play as mp4 file in flash player or quicktime as you know we can play mp4 files like this:
http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/mpeg4/streaming/example.html

Comment: The server does not need any codecs as the file is streamed down to the browser. The mp4 videos in the link you sent use quicktime on the client to play. Not all client's are going to have quicktime installed on there desktops. I would still convert to flv and use something like flowplayer as this format (flash) is more widely used.

Comment: yeah it does not need to have codec installed on the servre, but it needs some iis settings e.g: adding extention .mp4, mime setting for .mp4: video/mp4 etc..
So i have completed all these settings but still i m getting nothing when trying on webpage.. the code and path are accurate ...